# Retrieve WebService Array Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, web-services

I have to check if user input the correct code in order to retrieve these information. Please help! Code below is how my SOAP looks like:

```
<retrieveAudioInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <retrieveInfoResult>
            <Info>
              <date>string</date>
              <name>string</name>
              <id>int</id>
              <description>string</description>
              <url>string</url>
            </Info>
```

This is what I have done for my class to get data from web-service:

```
private void retrieveInfo(String code){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("code", code);


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;     
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        System.out.println(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {

               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
               infoList = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

               for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++){ 

               infoList[i] = response.getProperty(i).toString();
               Log.d("This is the response",infoList[i]);
      }      
} 
        catch (Exception e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

My Webservice:

```
POST /mobile/.../....asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/retrieveInfo"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <retrieveInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <code>string</code>
    </retrieveInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <retrieveInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <retrieveInfoResult>
        <Info>
          <date>string</date>
          <name>string</name>
          <id>int</id>
          <description>string</description>
          <url>string</url>
        </Info>
        <Info>
          <date>string</date>
          <name>string</name>
          <id>int</id>
          <description>string</description>
          <url>string</url>
        </Info>
      </retrieveInfoResult>
    </retrieveInfoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The error that I received is:

```
01-31 13:15:00.708: D/dalvikvm(13583): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 3% free 13108K/13447K, paused 12ms
01-31 13:15:00.713: I/dalvikvm-heap(13583): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.312MB for 2457616-byte allocation
01-31 13:15:00.738: D/dalvikvm(13583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 15507K/15879K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-31 13:15:00.788: D/dalvikvm(13583): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 15507K/15879K, paused 13ms
01-31 13:15:00.798: I/dalvikvm-heap(13583): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.476MB for 4367376-byte allocation
01-31 13:15:00.823: D/dalvikvm(13583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 19772K/20167K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-31 13:15:00.898: W/System.err(13583): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-31 13:15:00.898: W/System.err(13583):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-31 13:15:00.898: W/System.err(13583):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-31 13:15:00.898: W/System.err(13583):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:75)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:136)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at com.example.loginws.second.WebServiceCallExample(second.java:80)
01-31 13:15:00.903: W/System.err(13583):    at com.example.loginws.second.onCreate(second.java:32)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-31 13:15:00.908: W/System.err(13583):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-31 13:15:00.913: W/System.err(13583):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what do you want? do you want to parse the result or do you want to obtain the result??

Comment: Thanks for replying @edwin I need to obtain the result..

Comment: what have you done till in android part can provide some information

Comment: @edwin Ive updated my question above and inserted my class code.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14568880/1450401)

Comment: @edwin Ive changed my code.No more error. But still I couldnt see where my data go or if it is even being returned.

Comment: can u post the web service link

Comment: @edwin I cant show you the link as its confidential but Ive posted whatever important above.Thanks alot!!

Comment: is it getting any exception or any log cat message? still i don't know   whats the problem??

Comment: @edwin I just posted the message I received from my logcat and my app also does not crash. Just that I cant seem to see my input, eventhough i Log.d() my response.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs whenever you implement long running task on Main UI Thread. So i am sure you are trying to call `retrieveInfo()` inside the `onCreate()` method directly.

The best solution is to make a web call inside `doInBackground()` method of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). One more thing, AsyncTask is known as **Painless Threading** in android, because we programmer don't need to worry about management of threads once implemented.

Comment: Thanks @Paresh Mayani for the guidance! Will sure to keep that in mind always(:

Comment: It didnt totally solved my issue. Because of your guidance, logcat has just shown me my errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make an XML schema to compare to.
You can run validation of a SOAP message against an XML schema.

Comment: Thanks for replying Sean! Oh no no no! What I want to do is to actually retrieve all these data and display it in a listview (simple_list_item_2).