# asp.net web services in android application

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I am a newbie in android. Can anyone help me in running my asp.net web service in android application. I tried using SOAP OBJECT but the application force closes. The web service is the simple one which takes `my name` and returns `HELLO + "my name"`. HELP me in code.

Comment: If you are getting Force Close, that means there are problems/issues. Try to look at the **logcat** output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this is [**library**](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2) to full fill you need

This is [**Tutorial**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) telling how to use this library to call webservice

**Note** : Source code also available

don't forget to give internet permission on manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Refer** : See [**Dummy Class**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568880/1450401) calling SOAP method